# Rails Geocoding Distance Calulations are Incorrect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geocoding

I'm pretty stumped here with the following results from geocoding.
The first two are correct.  the last is obviously wrong.  Nothing was altered in the code between these calculations.   Any ideas on how to debug this?

```
Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between("allentown,pa","scranton,pa")
#=> 56.604020682719295

Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between("allentown,pa","harrisburg,pa")
#=> 77.94099956445362

Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between("allentown,pa","bethlehem,pa")
#=> 3365.993496166768
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple search results for "bethlehem,pa"

```rb
results = Geocoder.search("bethlehem,pa")
results.size # => 8
```

and not all of those results are in the US

```rb
results.map { |r| r.country_code }
 => ["br", "us", "us", "us", "us", "us", "us", "us"]
```

The hit from Brazil comes first. And if the result is ambigious, then this one is taken (see code below).
I assume the Brazil Bethlehem comes first because the state is called "pará" which is closer (string distance by whatever metric used) to "pa" than "pennsylvania"

`distance_between`

https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/f7a83fac8cf8564b79d017091004cbb9d406e4ae/lib/geocoder/calculations.rb#L84

will eventually call `coordinates`

https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/f7a83fac8cf8564b79d017091004cbb9d406e4ae/lib/geocoder.rb#L28

which looks like this:

```rb
def self.coordinates(address, options = {})
  if (results = search(address, options)).size > 0
    results.first.coordinates
  end
end
```

So augment your location string by country and you get a different result:

```rb
Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between("allentown,pa, USA","bethlehem,pa, USA")
# => 4.97795894130203
```

It boils down to location description as strings as often not being unique. There are multiple Paris', Berns, and for sure Bethlehems:-)

So it comes to no suprise that there are multiple allentowns as well:

```rb
require "geocoder"

allentowns = Geocoder.search("allentown,pa")
bethlehems = Geocoder.search("bethlehem,pa")


allentowns.each do |allentown|
  bethlehems.each do |bethlehem|
    distance = Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between([allentown.latitude, allentown.longitude], [bethlehem.latitude, bethlehem.longitude])
    puts "#{allentown.address} -> #{bethlehem.address}: #{distance}"
  end
end
```

reveals that there is **Allentown, Lehigh County, Pennsylvania, United States** and **Allentown, Pittsburgh, Allegheny County, Pennsylvania, United States**

Comment: Thank you so much! Your blood's worth bottlin'.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment and glad I could help.